# C# AddAccessRule for "This folder, subfolders and files"

Tags: c#, asp.net, access-rules

I have some code to apply permissions to a folder that works but it sets the folder permissions as 'Special' with it being applied as "This Folder and Files" where I need it to be applied as "This folder, subfolders and files". What am I doing wrong?

```
dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"DOMAIN\" + Account, FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, ControlType));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting it across two rules;

```
dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"DOMAIN\" + Account, FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, ControlType));
dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"DOMAIN\" + Account, FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, ControlType));
```